# How to use string to access the values of a typed object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object that looks like this

```
interface ProvideFeedbackFormProps {
  feedbackNature: FormikDropdownProps
  waybillNumber: FormikDropdownProps
  provideFeedback: FormikDropdownProps
  editorState?: string
  attachments?: string[]
}
```

and `FormikDropdownProps` looks like this

```
interface FormikDropdownProps {
  id: number
  value: string
}
```

When I run a loop on data that implements the above structure (`values` below is of type `ProvideFeedbackFormProps`), like so

```
for (const property in values) {
  const customField = values[property]
  customFields.push(customField)
}
```

I get an error at `values[property]` that says

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ProvideFeedbackFormProps'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ProvideFeedbackFormProps'
```

*Questions*

1. What is causing this behavior?
2. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (const property in values) { // property here will be typed as string
  const customField = values[property]
  customFields.push(customField)
}
```

The `property` value will be typed as a string. You can be more explicit and cast it to the correct type:

```
for (const property in values) {
  const customField = values[property as keyof ProvideFeedbackFormProps]
  customFields.push(customField)
}
```

Using the `keyof` keyword will cast the property type to be a key of `ProvideFeedbackFormProps`

You can follow the discussion on this [issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500)

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter typing error, "any" can be used as a universal type.

```
for (const property in values) {
    const any_values = values as any;
    const customField = any_values[property]
    customFields.push(customField)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. But in our project, we do not allow using any nor ts-ignore